# angular css manipulation or position change

Tags: css, angular, observable

[image]I have background image "Road" and another images two people standing, I need to dynamically change the position of the images(two people) as the width changes so that the two people will still standing at the road problem is that I cannot group the three images.

if we will use media query, example at max-width: 768 the top and left position: 800px, 1100px while the other one is 900px and 1300px. but once that it will go either way I need to change position so that they can stand still on the "road background image". I try media query, but it sucks once the width change at 800 the picture will be overlapping each other.

How do you do that? P.S. I am using angular 8.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you show some code/HTML and possibly an image? It is hard to visualise exactly what you need from the description.

Comment: I have include the picture above.